# Kotlin stuck on version 1.3.31 Android Studio project

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, kotlin

I'm new to this, I bought a Flutter project and am trying to start it in Android Studio.

The project used an older version of Android Gradle and I updated it to 7.0.2. But now when I try to build, I get the error:

[The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.3.40 and higher.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeqq2.png)

I checked the file android/**build.gradle** ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'

Here is the complete file:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
          url "https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap/"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I tried to change many versions but always the result is the same. I checked a lot of answers but still couldn't find what else could be the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.30'
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.7.1'
}
```

}